# Google search not working by html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So i was working on a project where i needed to make a search box by which when a button is clicked it searches the value in the input in new tab on google so i wrote some code to make it possible.

In order to make the google search by my page i wrote the following code
Html -

```
<div class="search-container">
                            <form>
                                <img src="imgs and icons/google.png" alt="" class="g-icon">
                                <input class="search" type="text" name="myInput"/>
                                <button id="search-button" onclick="googleSearch()"><img src="imgs and icons/search.png" class="search-icon" alt=""></button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

and here is javascript-

```
function googleSearch()
    {
        var text=document.getElementsByClassName("search").value;
        var cleanQuery = text.replace(" ","+",text);
        var url='http://www.google.com/search?q='+cleanQuery;
    
        window.location.href=url;
    }
```

Please tell me what mistake is there in this code and why is it not working

Answer (score 1):

1. `document.getElementsByClassName` return is `NodeList`

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

2. `String.prototype.replace()` only accept 2 parameters

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

> Your code is not working due to thing number 1

```js
function googleSearch()
    {
        var text=document.getElementsByClassName("search")[0].value;
        var cleanQuery = text.replace(" ","+");
        var url='http://www.google.com/search?q='+cleanQuery;
    
        window.location.href=url;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon!

So the first thing you should take a look at is what your `var text` is actually storing. [getElementsByClassname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array of elements ([HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)).

You can either index it for it's first element like so

```js
var text=document.getElementsByClassName("search")[0].value;

// or use querySelector()

var text = document.querySelector('.search').value // only returns the first match, for an array result see querySelectorAll()
```

Note: [querySelector('[css like string]')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) uses the same syntax as your css selectors so `.name` will look for elements with class of name and `#name` will look for elements with the id of name

Either way hope any of these help you out!

---

**Edit**; the replacements of whitespace characters is redundant if you only intend to use it with google, `?q=test value` yields the same results as `?q=test+value` or `?q=test%20value`

---

**Edit 2**;
In order to open the url in a new tab/window you cannot use `window.location.href`, window in this case refers to your current window instance, that's why they've provided us with [`window.open(url, target)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

target is used to indicate where the window should open to, usually `_blank`, see [target keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#target) for a more detailed explanation

Comment: So what i have to do to solve this problem ?

Comment: Either one of the snippets of code I've provided above should fix your code. If not, could you give a more detailed explanation of what the actual problem is? What do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: Actually this is also not working. So, i am making a searchbox in my web in which if we search something it redirects to google search with same query but when i am trying to do this with the following code it just refreshes the page nothing else.
if you can give me your email id so we can talk more comfortably.